# Зависание потока в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

При запуске кода в 2 потока(1-ый сканирует папку на наличие *dcm файлов и добавляет информацию в бд, 2-ой поток занимается копированием этих файлов в другую папку). Но проблема в том, что при выполнении 2 потока программа зависает и не происходит никаких действий.

```
def create_bd():
    connect_db = sqlite3.connect("study.sqlite")
    try:
        with closing(connect_db) as db:
            with open('screening_.sql', encoding="utf8") as f:
                db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
            db.commit()
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        pass


def anonymization_image(path_load, path_save):
    dcm = dicomio_read_file(path_load)
    list_tags = ['PatientName','PatientBirthTime','InstitutionAddress',
                 'PatientDeathDateInAlternativeCalendar', 'PatientComments',
                 'PersonAddress', 'InstitutionName', 'ResponsiblePerson',
                 'AdmissionID', 'DeviceSerialNumber', 'DeviceDescription']

    if hasattr(dcm, 'PatientAge'):
        dcm.PatientAge = '0000Y'
    if hasattr(dcm, 'PatientBirthDate'):
        dcm.PatientBirthDate = "19000101"

    for tag in list_tags:
        if hasattr(dcm, tag):
            dcm.tag = '*anonymized*'
    dcm.save_as(path_save)
    
    

def get_dcm_tags(path):
    modality = None
    gender = None
    study_description = None
    studydate = None

    dcm = dicomio_read_file(path)

    if hasattr(dcm, 'Modality'):
        modality = dcm.Modality
    if hasattr(dcm, 'PatientSex'):
        gender = dcm.PatientSex
    if hasattr(dcm, 'StudyDescription'):
        study_description = dcm.StudyDescription
    if hasattr(dcm, 'StudyTime'):
        studydate = dcm.StudyTime
    
    return dcm.PatientID, dcm.StudyInstanceUID, dcm.SeriesInstanceUID, gender, modality, study_description, studydate


def scaning_folder(folder, queue, event):
    """
    Собирает в указанной директории информацию 
    о снимках и заносит данные в бд
    """

    while not event.is_set():
        for dir_path, _, filenames in os.walk(folder):
            for file_name in filenames:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, "*.dcm"):
                    path_file = f'{dir_path}/{file_name}'
                    
                    # Заносим информацию в бд
                    append_study_in_bd(path_file)

                    # Отправляем данные во второй поток
                    queue.put(path_file)


def append_study_in_bd(path):

    patientid, study, series, gender, modality, study_description, studydate = get_dcm_tags(path)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    patient = PatientClass(patientid, gender)

    try:
        if PatientClass.check_patient(patientID=patientid):
            session.add(patient)
            session.flush()

        query_study = session.query(PatientClass).filter_by(patientID=patientid).first()
        studies = StudyClass(study, query_study.id, studydate, study_description)
        if StudyClass.check_study(studyUID=study):
            session.add(studies)
            session.flush()

        query = session.query(StudyClass).filter_by(studyUID=study).first()
        seriess = SeriesClass(query.id, series, modality, path)
        if SeriesClass.check_series(seriesUID=series):

            session.add(seriess)

        session.commit()

    except exc.IntegrityError:
        session.rollback()
        print("Произошла ошибка при добавление в бд")


def transfer_data(output_path, queue, event):

    while not event.is_set() or not queue.empty():

        path = queue.get()
        folder = path.replace("\\",'/')
        folder_series = folder.split('/')[-3]
        folder_imgs = folder.split('/')[-2]
        file_name = folder.split('/')[-1]
        try:
            os.makedirs(f"{output_path}/{folder_series}/{folder_imgs}")
        except FileExistsError:
            pass
        anonymization_image(folder, f"{output_path}/{folder_series}/{folder_imgs}/{file_name}")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_path = "C:/Users/Nikolau/Desktop/INFORMATION_ABOUT_STUDY/test"
    output_path = "data"

    create_bd()

    pipeline = queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
    event = threading.Event()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        executor.submit(scaning_folder, input_path, pipeline, event)
        executor.submit(transfer_data, output_path, pipeline, event)

        time.sleep(0.1)
        event.set()
```

Comment: А не может быть что они у вас дерутся за право доступа к одному файлу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В программе есть "гонки", т.е. ее выполнение зависит от того, какие потоки и в каком порядке будут выполнятся.

Главная проблема - это то, что через 100 мс после запуска потоков устанавливается `event`, который интерпретируется потоками, как запрос на остановку. Поэтому, вполне вероятна следующая последовательность событий:

1. главный поток запускает два рабочих потока
2. `scaning_folder` добавляет элемент (или элементы) в очередь
3. `transfer_data` достает и обрабатывает элементы
4. взводится `event`
5. в какой-то момент `tranfer_data` заканчивает обрабатывать все доступные на данный момент элементы в очереди
6. `tranfer_data` идет на новый виток цикла и тут получается, что очередь пуста и `event.is_set` - обработка заканчивается и поток выходит. При этом `scaning_folder` продолжит выполнение, как только придет его очередь.

Исправить можно по разному. В первую очередь нужно изменить условие ожидания и саму логику остановки программы. Вероятно, она должна останавливаться, когда закончит обрабатывать все файлы. Т.е. `event` нужно взводить не из главного потока, а из `scaning_folder`. А главный поток, должен ждать, когда закончится `transfer_data`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте данным способом

```
import threading

#### для создания очереди
LOCK = threading.Lock()

### запретить доступ к файлу другим потокам
# LOCK.acquire()

# разрешить доступ к файлу другим потокам
# LOCK.release()

def create_bd():
    connect_db = sqlite3.connect("study.sqlite")
    try:
        LOCK.acquire()
        with closing(connect_db) as db:
            with open('screening_.sql', encoding="utf8") as f:
                db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
            db.commit()
        LOCK.release()
    except:
        LOCK.release()


def anonymization_image(path_load, path_save):
    dcm = dicomio_read_file(path_load)
    list_tags = ['PatientName', 'PatientBirthTime', 'InstitutionAddress',
             'PatientDeathDateInAlternativeCalendar', 'PatientComments',
             'PersonAddress', 'InstitutionName', 'ResponsiblePerson',
             'AdmissionID', 'DeviceSerialNumber', 'DeviceDescription']

    if hasattr(dcm, 'PatientAge'):
        dcm.PatientAge = '0000Y'
    if hasattr(dcm, 'PatientBirthDate'):
        dcm.PatientBirthDate = "19000101"

    for tag in list_tags:
        if hasattr(dcm, tag):
            dcm.tag = '*anonymized*'
    dcm.save_as(path_save)


def get_dcm_tags(path):
    modality = None
    gender = None
    study_description = None
    studydate = None

    dcm = dicomio_read_file(path)

    if hasattr(dcm, 'Modality'):
       modality = dcm.Modality
    if hasattr(dcm, 'PatientSex'):
        gender = dcm.PatientSex
    if hasattr(dcm, 'StudyDescription'):
        study_description = dcm.StudyDescription
    if hasattr(dcm, 'StudyTime'):
        studydate = dcm.StudyTime

    return dcm.PatientID, dcm.StudyInstanceUID, dcm.SeriesInstanceUID, gender,             modality, study_description, studydate


def scaning_folder(folder, queue, event):
    """
    Собирает в указанной директории информацию
       о снимках и заносит данные в бд
    """

    while not event.is_set():
        for dir_path, _, filenames in os.walk(folder):
            for file_name in filenames:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, "*.dcm"):
                    path_file = f'{dir_path}/{file_name}'

                    # Заносим информацию в бд
                    append_study_in_bd(path_file)

                    # Отправляем данные во второй поток
                    queue.put(path_file)


def append_study_in_bd(path):
    patientid, study, series, gender, modality, study_description, studydate =             
    get_dcm_tags(
    path)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    patient = PatientClass(patientid, gender)

    try:
        if PatientClass.check_patient(patientID=patientid):
            session.add(patient)
            session.flush()

        query_study = session.query(PatientClass).filter_by(
            patientID=patientid).first()
        studies = StudyClass(study, query_study.id, studydate,
                         study_description)
        if StudyClass.check_study(studyUID=study):
            session.add(studies)
            session.flush()

        query = session.query(StudyClass).filter_by(studyUID=study).first()
        seriess = SeriesClass(query.id, series, modality, path)
        if SeriesClass.check_series(seriesUID=series):
            session.add(seriess)

        session.commit()

    except exc.IntegrityError:
        session.rollback()
        print("Произошла ошибка при добавление в бд")


def transfer_data(output_path, queue, event):
    while not event.is_set() or not queue.empty():

        path = queue.get()
        folder = path.replace("\\", '/')
        folder_series = folder.split('/')[-3]
        folder_imgs = folder.split('/')[-2]
        file_name = folder.split('/')[-1]
        try:
           os.makedirs(f"{output_path}/{folder_series}/{folder_imgs}")
        except FileExistsError:
            pass
        anonymization_image(folder,
                        f"{output_path}/{folder_series}/{folder_imgs}/{file_name}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_path = "C:/Users/Nikolau/Desktop/INFORMATION_ABOUT_STUDY/test"
    output_path = "data"

    create_bd()

    pipeline = queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
   event = threading.Event()


    threadList = []
    thread_1 = threading.Thread(target='Функция', args=['Аргументы'])
    thread_2 = threading.Thread(target='Функция', args=['Аргументы'])
    threadList.append(thread_1)
    thread_1.start()
    threadList.append(thread_2)
    thread_2.start()

    import time
    while threading.active_count() > 2:
        time.sleep(1)

   for thread in threadList:
        thread.join()
```

Вам нужно будет дополнить доступ в остальных случаях.